# Multiple conditions in a while tryParse

Tags: c#, console, tryparse

I want to be able to stop people entering anything other than an int value between 0 and 19.

Using tryParse, I can ensure than only integer values can be entered. Using a standard while loop, I can ensure that only integers between 0 and 19 can be entered, but I am struggling to combine to two values.

So far, the only way I have made it work its by separating the two loops and it looks messy. Like so:

```
        while (!(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out quant)))
        {

           Console.Clear();
           Console.WriteLine("Current total: £" + total.ToString("0.00\n"));
           Console.WriteLine("That is an invalid quantity. Please enter the quantity again");

        }

        while ((quant >= 20 || quant < 0))
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Current total: £" + total.ToString("0.00\n"));
            Console.WriteLine("That is an invalid quantity. Please enter the quantity again");


            while (!(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out quant)))               {


                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Current total: £" + total.ToString("0.00\n"));
                Console.WriteLine("That is an invalid quantity. Please enter the quantity again");

            }
        }
```

This is the only way I can get the two values to loop over if an incorrect value is repeatedly entered.

How can I use multiple values to use a single loop?

Comment: `while (!(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out quant)) || quant > 19 || quant < 0)`?

Comment: I tried that, and unless I mistyped something, it won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can *combine* conditions in one loop:

```
// we want: Console.ReadLine() being an integer value (quant) and
//          quant >= 0 and
//          quant <= 19
while (!(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out quant) && 
         quant >= 0 && 
         quant <= 19)) {
  Console.Clear();

  Console.WriteLine("Current total: £" + total.ToString("0.00\n"));
  Console.WriteLine("That is an invalid quantity. Please enter the quantity again");
}

// quant is integer and within [0..19] range
```

Comment: Hello. Yes, I know I can combine them, but it won't work for me (that's why I am left with that mess I posted!).

I will try your code. I must have mistyped something somewhere!

Comment: @Matt: Could, you, please, be more specific in "it won't work for me" - what's wrong with the simple conditions combination?

Comment: Okay I tried your code and it works. Perhaps it is because I was using OR instead of AND?

Either way, thank you.